# OG groups: How to check if user is a member or not?

Tags: users, organic-groups

What code can I use to check if a user is a member of a group?

Answer (score 6):

For the 7.x-2.x branch of Organic Groups you need to use the following code.

```
og_is_member('node', $gid, 'user', $user)
```

'node' is the entity type. The function [og_is_member](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!og!og.module/function/og_is_member/7) requires 4 parameters to return the correct value.

Comment: Which Drupal version are you using? The parameters you use are different from [the ones defined from the Drupal 7 version of OG](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/og_is_member/7).

Answer (score 5):

In Drupal 7 for the For the 7.x-1.x branch of Organic Groups, you can use [`og_is_member()`](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/og_is_member/7).

```
$gid = 12;
if (og_is_member($gid)) {
  drupal_set_message('Current logged in user is member');
}
```

```
$gid = 12;
$account = user_load(3);
if (og_is_member($gid, 'user', $account)) {
  drupal_set_message('User id 3 is member of group 12');
}
```

Comment: And where do i put this code? I put it in node.tpl.php but its not working.. Can you help me please? Thank you!

Comment: You could put it anywhere, but make sure you use the correct group id (gid)

Comment: I get an error: Illegal offset type in og_get_entity_groups() (line 1986 ... ) . when i add: <?php 
$account = $user;
if (og_is_member('19', 'user', $account)) {
  print('User id 3 is member of group 12');
} 
?>

Comment: @Dzoni I don't know if that makes a difference, but the gid should be a number not a string.