# How to use og_is_member() API?

Tags: organic-groups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OG groups: How to check if user is a member or not?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58940/og-groups-how-to-check-if-user-is-a-member-or-not)

I don't know how to use this: http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/calls/og_is_member/7

I want to check if user is a member of group or not.

Can someone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: I have node--group.tpl.php And in here i want to add that code for each group. So if user is not a member to show him a subscribe button or something...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what difficulty you're having using the function or what Drupal version you're on, but according to [drupalize.me](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/og_is_member/7), in Drupal 7 `og_is_member()` takes parameters `$gid` (ID of group), `$entity_type` (defaults to 'user'), `$entity` (defaults to current user), and `$states` (optional, defaults to all), and returns `TRUE` if the entity (e.g. current user by default) belongs to the group.

For example, to find out if the current user is a member of group 4, I would use something like,

```
$current_user = global $user;
if (og_is_member(4, 'user', $current_user)) {
  // show the user some stuff from group 4
}
```

The above code is not tested but should get you started.

Comment: I have node--group.tpl.php

And in here i want to add that code for each group.

So if user is not a member to show him a subscribe button or something

Comment: Okay, so then you would put that inside the `if() {...}` and add `== FALSE`

Comment: See the [php.net page on `if()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) for more about how to do that.

Comment: This answer is not accurate. The $group_type parameter was added.